# How to fix Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/ ...., on installing php 5.6 in docker?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, php-5.6

I need to run an old project which needs php 5.6 and mysql 5.5. Inorder to accomblish this I have created a docker but below errors occured on docker compose. when I tried with php 7.3 it works fine  but able to install 5.6

```
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch/main/binary- 
 amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch-updates/main/binary- 
 amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian- 
 security/dists/stretch/updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found 
 [IP:151.101.130.132 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used 
 instead.
ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt- 
get install -y         git .....' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Below are the files I used
docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:

# The Application
app:
   build:
  context: ./
  dockerfile: app.dockerfile
working_dir: /var/www
volumes:
  - ./public:/var/www
  - ./php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
environment:
  - "DB_PORT=3306"
  - "DB_HOST=database"

# The Web Server
web:
  build:
    context: ./
    dockerfile: web.dockerfile
  working_dir: /var/www
  volumes_from:
    - app
  ports:
    - 8080:80

# The Database
database:
    image: mysql:5.7-debian
  volumes:
    - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
  environment:
    - "MYSQL_DATABASE=homestead"
    - "MYSQL_USER=homestead"
    - "MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret"
    - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret"
  ports:
      - "33061:3306"

volumes:
  dbdata:
```

app.dockerfile

```
 FROM php:5.6.15-cli

 RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git zip unzip
 RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql

 RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin 
 --filename=composer
```

web.dockerfile

```
 FROM nginx:1.10

 ADD vhost.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Comment: Also see [Debian stretch repositories 404 Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76094428/debian-stretch-repositories-404-not-found), though the specific advice there may not help prebuilt archaic Docker images.

Answer (score 0):

Debian stretch is not supported by the Debian project. Like PHP 5.6, it is ancient and has been superseded multiple times.

You'll need to either find another source of the deb packages or compile the source code yourself.

---

It would be probably better to invest the time in modernising the project (so it can run on supported software) instead.