# Dockerfile on Mac Studio with M1 chip can't run apt-get commands

Tags: docker, magento-1.9, apple-m1, apt-get

Below is my Dockerfile. This file is successfully building on a colleague's Windows computer, as well as another's Mac Studio running Ventura (just like me except it has an M2 chip, and I have an M1 chip). This is to support a Magento 1.9.x install, so if anyone knows a good docker setup for that on MacOS with an M1 chip, please do tell!

The error:

`failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt-get -y update" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100`.

Full log out put with errors:

```
 docker-compose up -d
[+] Building 4.3s (6/33)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 3.38kB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/php:5.6-apache                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  1.6s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 522B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => CACHED [ 1/29] FROM docker.io/library/php:5.6-apache@sha256:0a40fd273961b99d8afe69a61a68c73c04bc0caa9de384d3b2dd9e7986eec86d                                                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => ERROR [ 2/29] RUN apt-get -y update                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            2.7s
------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
 > [ 2/29] RUN apt-get -y update:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
#0 0.486 Ign:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
#0 0.497 Ign:2 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
#0 0.519 Ign:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
#0 0.529 Ign:4 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates Release                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
#0 0.542 Ign:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release
#0 0.543 Ign:6 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
#0 0.558 Ign:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates Release
#0 0.704 Ign:8 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main armhf Packages
#0 0.704 Ign:9 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main armhf Packages
#0 0.721 Ign:6 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
#0 0.732 Ign:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
#0 0.751 Ign:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
#0 0.862 Ign:9 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main armhf Packages
#0 0.874 Ign:6 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
#0 0.879 Ign:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main armhf Packages
#0 1.031 Ign:8 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main armhf Packages
#0 1.071 Ign:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
#0 1.093 Ign:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
#0 1.156 Ign:9 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main armhf Packages
#0 1.176 Ign:6 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
#0 1.239 Ign:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main armhf Packages
#0 1.317 Ign:9 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main armhf Packages
#0 1.339 Ign:6 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
#0 1.371 Ign:8 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main armhf Packages
#0 1.396 Ign:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
#0 1.414 Ign:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
#0 1.496 Ign:9 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main armhf Packages
#0 1.511 Ign:6 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
#0 1.544 Ign:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main armhf Packages
#0 1.655 Err:9 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main armhf Packages
#0 1.655   404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.130.132 80]
#0 1.684 Ign:8 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main armhf Packages
#0 1.701 Ign:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
#0 1.711 Ign:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
#0 1.852 Ign:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main armhf Packages
#0 1.991 Ign:8 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main armhf Packages
#0 2.023 Ign:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
#0 2.050 Ign:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
#0 2.185 Ign:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main armhf Packages
#0 2.328 Err:8 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main armhf Packages
#0 2.328   404  Not Found
#0 2.349 Ign:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
#0 2.371 Ign:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
#0 2.515 Err:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main armhf Packages
#0 2.515   404  Not Found
#0 2.570 Reading package lists...
#0 2.654 W: The repository 'http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates Release' does not have a Release file.
#0 2.655 W: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release' does not have a Release file.
#0 2.655 W: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
#0 2.655 E: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/stretch/updates/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.130.132 80]
#0 2.655 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found
#0 2.655 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch-updates/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found
#0 2.655 E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt-get -y update" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100
```

Also, it's getting 404s, but again, this same Dockerfile builds on my colleagues computers.

The Dockerfile:

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 php:5.6-apache

ENV XDEBUG_PORT 9000

# Install System Dependencies

RUN apt-get -y update #errors out here, let alone the next one!

RUN apt-get update \
    && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    software-properties-common \
    && apt-get update \
    && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y \
    nodejs \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libicu-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libmcrypt-dev \
    libedit-dev \
    libedit2 \
    libxslt1-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    apt-utils \
    gnupg \
    redis-tools \
    mariadb-client \
    git \
    vim \
    wget \
    curl \
    lynx \
    psmisc \
    unzip \
    tar \
    cron \
    rsync \
    bash-completion \
    && apt-get clean

# Install Magento Dependencies

RUN docker-php-ext-configure \
    gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/; \
    docker-php-ext-install \
    opcache \
    gd \
    bcmath \
    intl \
    mbstring \
    pdo_mysql \
    soap \
    xsl \
    zip \
    sockets


RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli

RUN apt-get install -y apt-transport-https

# Install Node, NVM, NPM and Gulp

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash - \
    && apt-get install -y nodejs build-essential \
    && npm i -g gulp yarn

# Install Composer

# Install Ruby and Compass

# Getting the rvm necessary data via url protocol.
RUN apt-get install -y ruby-dev

RUN ruby -v

# Finally install compass.
RUN gem install compass

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --version=1.10.17 --install-dir=/usr/local/bin/ --filename=composer

# Install Code Sniffer

RUN git clone https://github.com/magento/marketplace-eqp.git ~/.composer/vendor/magento/marketplace-eqp
RUN cd ~/.composer/vendor/magento/marketplace-eqp && composer install
RUN ln -s ~/.composer/vendor/magento/marketplace-eqp/vendor/bin/phpcs /usr/local/bin;

ENV PATH="/var/www/.composer/vendor/bin/:${PATH}"


RUN git clone -b XDEBUG_2_5_5 https://github.com/xdebug/xdebug.git /root/xdebug \
&& cd /root/xdebug && ./rebuild.sh 

# Install Mhsendmail

RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install golang-go \
   && mkdir /opt/go \
   && export GOPATH=/opt/go \
   && go get github.com/mailhog/mhsendmail

# Install Magerun 1

RUN wget https://files.magerun.net/n98-magerun-1.97.15.phar \
    && chmod +x ./n98-magerun-1.97.15.phar \
    && mv ./n98-magerun-1.97.15.phar /usr/local/bin/magerun

# Configuring system

ADD /.docker/config/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
ADD /.docker/config/magento.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/magento.conf
ADD /.docker/config/custom-xdebug.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/custom-xdebug.ini
COPY /.docker/bin/* /usr/local/bin/
COPY /.docker/users/* /var/www/
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/*
RUN ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/magento.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/magento.conf

RUN curl -o /etc/bash_completion.d/m2install-bash-completion https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yvoronoy/m2install/master/m2install-bash-completion
RUN echo "source /etc/bash_completion" >> /root/.bashrc
RUN echo "source /etc/bash_completion" >> /var/www/.bashrc

RUN chmod 777 -Rf /var/www /var/www/.* \
    && chown -Rf www-data:www-data /var/www /var/www/.* \
    && usermod -u 1000 www-data \
    && chsh -s /bin/bash www-data\
    && a2enmod rewrite \
    && a2enmod headers

VOLUME /var/www/html
WORKDIR /var/www/html
```

I've tried setting the platform at the top of the Dckerfile like this:
`FROM --platform=linux/amd64 php:5.6-apache` and many other variations such as `FROM --platform=linux/x86_64 php:5.6-apache`. I've looked at options https://hub.docker.com/_/php/tags?page=1&name=5.6-apache, but can't get anything to work. For whatever reason, apt-get just won't go.

Comment: You can't just give us the very last log messages and leave everything else out; the prior messages will explain _why_ it has an exit status of 100.

Comment: (mind, I'm _guessing_ that it was a network failure, and you want to look at any firewall tools you're using, but without more complete logs that's nothing but a guess).

Comment: Sorry, yes of course! I've added the full log messages.

Comment: Also see [How to fix Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/ ...., on installing php 5.6 in docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76280045/how-to-fix-failed-to-fetch-http-deb-debian-org-on-installing-php-5-6-in).

Comment: what is the command you are running? are you using `buildx`?

Comment: @bujian the command I'm using is ````docker-compose up -d```` and have tried ````docker-compose build```` as well

Comment: This sounds like a network configuration issue outside of docker. Can you reach the URL/IP in question on your host?

Comment: Okay, HTTP 404s while downloading individual packages are a consequence of failure to successfully download an updated package _index_ prior.

Comment: (that said, this illustrates one of the reasons I consider Docker oversold; people claim that it creates reproducible builds, but they're only reproducible if all the network dependencies are exactly the same as they were during the last attempt; compare to Nix, where build steps are run in a sandbox where they have no access to networking at all, _unless_ that step was able to declare the hash of its expected output before it was even started).

Comment: Hardcoding `--platform` may not be ideal for multi-arch images. You may want to:
1. Use `FROM --platform=$BUILDPLATFORM` instead.
2. Check if the dependencies you're getting with `apt` actually provide `arm64` binaries in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding the below commands to my Dockerfile, before the `apt-get` commands, did the trick. Was slow to download, but the Docker containers came up and it works as expected.

```
RUN sed -i s/deb.debian.org/archive.debian.org/g /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN sed -i 's|security.debian.org|archive.debian.org/|g' /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN sed -i '/stretch-updates/d' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64 .` to build an image that can run on both AMD64 (x86) and ARM64 (the M1)

Answer (score 0):

None of the other answers solved the issue, but I found a good suggestion in [this issue](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/10240#issuecomment-1419974066) which suggested uninstalling:

- docker
- docker-compose
- docker desktop

Then re-install everything. This helped fixed the issue.